# MSVC vs Clang/GCC bug during overload resolution of function templates one of which contains a parameter pack

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-templates, parameter-pack, pack-expansion

I was using parameter pack when I noticed that one such case(shown below) compiles fine in gcc and clang but not in msvc:

```
template<class T> void func(T a, T b= T{})
{
    
}
template<class T, class... S> void func(T a, S... b)
{

}
 
int main()
{
    func(1); // Should this call succeed? 
}
```

Here is the link for verifying the same: https://godbolt.org/z/8KsrcnMez

As can be seen the above program fails in msvc with the error message:

```
<source>(13): error C2668: 'func': ambiguous call to overloaded function
<source>(6): note: could be 'void func<int,>(T)'
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
<source>(2): note: or       'void func<int>(T,T)'
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
<source>(13): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
```

But the same compiles fine with gcc and clang.

Which compiler(s) is right here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC is right in rejecting the code. According to [temp.func.order#5.example-2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.func.order#5.example-2) the call `func(1)` is ambiguous. The example given in the standard is as follows:

> Note: Since, in a call context, such **type deduction considers only parameters for which there are explicit call arguments, some parameters are ignored (namely, function parameter packs, parameters with default arguments, and ellipsis parameters)**.
>
> ```
> template<class T         > void g(T, T = T());          // #3
> template<class T, class... U> void g(T, U ...);         // #4
>
> void h() {
>  g(42);                                                // error: ambiguous
> }
> ```

This means that in the example in question, the call `func(1)` is ambiguous as well.

##### Errata

Note that [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) has errata in below given example:

> ```
> template<class T>
> void g(T, T = T()); // #1
> template<class T, class... U>
> void g(T, U...);    // #2
>
> void h()
> {
>    g(42); // calls #1 due to the tie-breaker between parameter pack and omitted parameter
> }
> ```

As can be seen in the above example, cpprefernce incorrectly says that the first overload `#1` should be choosen.

This has been fixed in recent [edit](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/language/function_template&diff=140392&oldid=139771) that i made.

Comment: The standard actually has an example saying that this call is ambiguous: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.func.order#5.example-2

Comment: @user17732522 I have updated the answer to say that cppreference has an errata. And that the call `func(1)` is ambiguous according to the standard. And also the msvc is correct.

Comment: @user17732522 Also, i have made an [edit](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/language/function_template&diff=140392&oldid=139771) fixing the example on cppreference.

Comment: I was not claiming that the example in the standard is definitively correct. A similar example required correction after [CWG 1395](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1395), see https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2559. I just wanted to show that it might not be as straight-forward as citing cppreference and that "_The same can also be inferred from temp.deduct.partial._" may not be obvious if there is an example saying the opposite.

Comment: @user17732522 I see. In any case i have mentioned both(i.e., the standard's example and the cppreference). Also at least after the edit, cppreference matches the standard. Btw i thought that you were claiming that *"the example in the standard is definitively correct"* because i saw the downvote on my answer and i assumed it was you suggesting that i should correct my answer.

Comment: Not my downvote. Sometimes it is forgotten to update examples (which are non-normative) with normative changes and this one has been in there since C++11. I think the question is whether "for which F does not have a corresponding parameter" in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.partial#11 (from CWG1395) applies to the defaulted function parameter without explicit argument in the call as well, or whether it doesn't. I am not sure because https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.func.order#5.sentence-1 says (again non-normative) something about parameters being ignored.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, looking at [temp.deduct.partial#11] and [temp.func.order#5] it is not obvious that whether the call `func(1);` should succeed or not. Most probably the wording needs some clarification.

Comment: @user17732522 I also asked a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671622/msvc-not-able-to-disambiguate-between-function-templates-when-one-of-them-contai) that does not involve a function parameter pack. I am not sure what the standard says about that example.

Comment: @user17732522 _temp.func.order#5.sentence-1 says (again non-normative) something about parameters being ignored_ Not sure about packs and ellipsis, but there is https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.viable#2.3.sentence-2. The part about ellipsis may be covered by the previous bullet. And packs are ignored because functions produced from their templates do not have packs, but a concrete number of parameters? This part is susp.